# How do I get VSCode to auto-indent this correctly?

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation, auto-indent

I'm calling a function and I want the parameters to be on separate lines so I can comment them, like this:

```js
doStuff(
    doItWell.quality,         // quality setting
    doItFast * 100,           // speed setting
    doItCheap.checkbox.value  //price setting
);
alert("done");
```

but VSCode auto-indent always does this:

```js
doStuff(
    doItWell.quality,         // quality setting
    doItFast * 100,           // speed setting
    doItCheap.checkbox.value  //price setting
    );
    alert("done");
```

Note the extra indent on the `alert()` line.

Prettier gets it, so when I type it in and it auto-formats it's all good, but as soon as I run VSCode's auto-indent I get the extra indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prettier gets it, so when I type it in and it auto-formats it's all good, but as soon as I run VSCode's auto-indent I get the extra indentation.

So you basically need to set Prettier as the default formatted. Go to the settings (by `Ctrl`+`,`) and set "Editor: Default Formatter" to `Prettier`.

This will override your 'default' vscode formatter

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work straight out of the box, what worked was not using the `re-indent lines` function, but the `format document` function. I swapped the keybindings and now it works for me.

Comment: @stib I was just about to comment on how were you invoking the command. Glad to know that you got it running.